# Gsxr 750 k1 loss of power after trying to jump

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, gsxr

Tried to jump start the bike which did have some power. The black and red connectors touched. Sparks followed. The battery is ok but the bike is dead only the neutral light showing. Any ideas where to look. 30 amp green fuse looks good and so do the fuses near the right handle bar. Any help much appreciated.

Thanks